# What is the best archive lib for VB?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am looking for a good archiver lib (DLL) for VB?

A fast DLL that can pack and unpack file fast and easy!

If possible to be able to pack in .rar & .zip format

tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). It works very well with VB.NET, and is freely available under the MS-PL license.

> DotNetZip is an easy-to-use, FAST,
>   FREE class library and toolset for
>   manipulating zip files or folders. Zip
>   and Unzip is easy: with DotNetZip,
>   .NET applications written in VB, C# -
>   any .NET language - can easily create,
>   read, extract, or update zip files.
>   For Mono or MS .NET.

You can get it from [codeplex](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), or install the [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip) (`Install-Package DotNetZip`).

Answer (score 1):

[7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) has an [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) that you can use from VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage` class.